# Is there a way I can prevent dashed border to merge?

Tags: html, css, border, html-table

I have `border:dashed` applied to my table cells and in some places the dashes merges with the ones of the other table cell. See the image below. Is there a way I can prevent this without applying the style to the row directly?

[image: the merged dashes emphasized with red]

Later edit: I have applied the style to the `tr` directly and got the same result.

Comment: Give the border to only one side. `td {border-bottom:1px dashed black;}`

Comment: We need to see your CSS, but it sounds like you can set the bottom border on the table **rows** instead of the table **cells**

Comment: I think this question is already answered and best explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786963/non-uniform-dashed-border-in-table-cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be collapsing the `border` of your `table` element, so get rid of that and use `border-collapse: separate;` with `border-spacing: 1px;` instead

```
table {
    border-spacing: 1px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

table tr td {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sxv5P/)

<s>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sxv5P/1/)</s> *(See the corners when the borders are `collapsed`)*

Comment: Your answer is right, it really does what i ask. But the result is still ugly and i think i'll end up using background image to get the desired effect - of a continous, equally dashed border. Thanks a lot for the info!